# PagedListPager lost params, how to enforce keywords in urls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I have 3 search params(location, map, time) in the controller, and in the view, I have written the following code for the pagedlist, somehow it doesn't work well. If i only filter by location, the first page of result is correct but from the second page on, it returns me nothing because the url has changed that only the applied search string is showed in the url. for example:

page1:

```
index?location=1&map=&time=
```

but when i click on page2, the url turns:

```
index?page=2&location=1
```

2 params lost.
how can i enforce all the params are included in the url, even they have no values?

```
eg. index?location=&map=&time=
```

my PagedListPager code:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page =>Url.Action("Index", 
new { page,  location= Request.QueryString["location"], 
     map= Request.QueryString["map"], 
     time= Request.QueryString["time"] }))
```

Comment: can you post your controller? also why you don't use the Viewbag ?but you can try this
time= Request.QueryString["time"] != null ? Request.QueryString["time"].ToString():string.Empty

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, if a value is empty, there is no reason to even have it in the QueryString, which is why I would assume the parameters are not being included. How did you get `&map=&time=`?

Comment: If i append the url with &map=&time= at the end manually so the page works. You are right the value is empty so they are excluded, that's why i am looking for a way to include them all the time.

Comment: Can you show what your routing definition looks like?